# can't merge on index. tried using join, merge,

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Tried combining the to dataframes on index using the methods below

```
df_result = pd.concat([df1,df2])

pd.merge(df2, df1, left_index=True,right_index=True)

df2.join(df1)
```

But it's not working, nothing is merged.

Is it because I converted the series to a dataframe df1. Do I have to set index somehow on the df1 ?

df1

```
    signal
6        1
7       -1
8       -1
9       -1
10      -1
11       1
```

df2

```
   my_id  
0  638BB   
1  639AA   
2  sddsf   
3  233dd  
4  rere3   
5  erre3  
6  jjk54   
7  sdg88 
8  sdfd2  
9  sdfd3
```

expected result = df_result

```
   my_id  signal
0  638BB   NaN
1  639AA   NaN
2  sddsf   NaN
3  233dd   NaN
4  rere3   NaN
5  erre3   NaN
6  jjk54    1
7  sdg88   -1
8  sdfd2   -1
9  sdfdf.  -1
```

Comment: `df_result = pd.merge(df2, df1, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')`

Comment: didn't work... updated question

Comment: It does work . . . try again.

Comment: yeah it should work. And also try setting the index on both df's to make sure the index is in pace.

Comment: @It_is_Chris Yes it did work, I didn't  set the output  as you did it. Thank you